# Error: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to automatically select a tab with JQuery.
  here is my code. I have tried to initialize JQuery but still getting the same Error.

```
 $("ul.tabs").tabs();
 $( "#messages" ).tabs( "option", "active", 2 );
```

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" style="top: -78px;width:100%;">
  <div class="liner"></div>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" title="welcome">
      <span class="round-tabs one">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" ></i>
       </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" title="Email forwarding">
      <span class="round-tabs two">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" ></i>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab" title="Edit your spins here">
      <span class="round-tabs three">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ></i>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$("ul.tabs").tabs(); $("ul.tabs").tabs( "option", "active", 2);`

Comment: could you please explain it to me it is still not working

Comment: I cannot know for sure, because you did not include any html, that is why this is a comment. But it is obvious, that you initialized `tabs` widget on `"ul.tabs"` element, but are trying to change tabs option on something else.

Comment: i have updatetd the question i included some part of my html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a solution to this issue. This is works perfectly for me.

var activeTab = "#messages";

$('a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');

Answer (score 1):

Follow html from the first example https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

You initialized tabs widget on "ul.tabs" element, but are trying to change tabs option on something else.

```
$("ul.tabs").tabs();  
$("ul.tabs").tabs("option", "active", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML does not match your selector so I have updated the html with assumptions and the script for that.  Updated to show/use an index within a list of targets.

```js
var mytabs = $("#mytabs");
mytabs.tabs();
// set by index, a bit inflexible for you  
//mytabs.tabs("option", "active", 2);
// get the index in the list and use it
var atarget = $('#messages').index(".mytargets");
mytabs.tabs("option", "active", atarget );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="mytabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" style="top: -78px;width:100%;">
      <div class="liner"></div>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" title="welcome">
          <span class="round-tabs one">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" ></i>
           </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" title="Email forwarding">
          <span class="round-tabs two">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" ></i>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab" title="Edit your spins here">
          <span class="round-tabs three">
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ></i>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
<div id="home" class="mytargets">I am home</div>
<div id="profile" class="mytargets">I am profile</div>
<div id="messages" class="mytargets">I am messages</div>
</div>
```

Note I updated so that if you add NEW tabs, the one with id `messages` will still get the focus/active state.

Comment: it is still not working for me . it only selects the tab in the unordered list and  it doestnt select the inner div. it also changes my design. i will be sharing the rest of my html.

Comment: Yes, I did have to make assumptions without the target elements available; and got this working with that.  Keep in mind this is index related so you need an "index" - for example as I put in my update. Note your UL does NOT have a class named "tabs" as in your selector